# How to remove white bar that appears on top of screen for larger devices on android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

While running my app with AVD on android studio, with a tall device like Pixel 6, a strange white bar appears on top of the screen. However, when i run it with an average sized device like a Pixel 2, it doesn't show. How can i fix this?

[image: White Bar across top of screen]

Unsure where to go from here to be honest, any suggestions and explanations are very welcome :)

Comment: Have you seen/tried: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector

Comment: I hadn't seen that before, so thank you, but unfortunately this didn't have any information to help me resolve my issue :(

Comment: I would review the 'good' and 'bad' versions of your layout/device render to see if you can identify the layer/view issue. Otherwise should edit your post to include details of your layout XML, if you (or any libraries) are doing any dynamic alterations, if it always appears or just in certain parts of your app, and how you are testing (physical or emulator).

Comment: @CJames Just switched from Windows to Mac and I'm having this exact same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Update: Created a new emulator one Android version below (Tiramisu) and the issue is resolved, though the status bar isn't aligned with the camera.